# Spring Security. Как сделать авторизацию на rest сервисе

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

Есть rest сервис, хочется сделать в нем авторизацию не через веб форму, а просто через post запрос. Есть какие то варианты сделать это кроме jwt? Подскажите как реализовать/куда смотреть :)

Comment: Попробуй сначала реализовать Basic Authentication. Вот [туториал](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication), в котором описано как это сделать

Comment: плюсую за  Basic Authentication можно добашить в header `Authorization: Basic Base64(login:password)`  более подробно - [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#:~:text=In%20basic%20HTTP%20authentication%2C%20a,joined%20by%20a%20single%20colon%20%3A%20.)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете отправить POST запрос с заголовками (headers) в заголовках указать два ключа

login - значение

password - значение

Главное, чтобы сервис работал через https, иначе это будет небезопасно.

Comment: Не безопасно так делать.

Comment: Почему? Как именно могут узнать логин и пароль если это POST запрос работающий через Https?

Comment: Потому что HTTPS - не панаценя.